# FreeBSD 11.2 - 256 color support in console window

Tags: terminal, freebsd, console, xterm

I installed FreeBSD 11.2 on my DELL Latitude E7470 with UEFI (might be important). By default it does not install a GUI and that is fine by me (for now). Using the `<Alt>`+`<Fn>` keys I can switch between different virtual terminals.

#### I cannot change the colors with vt

I tried with the following in */boot/loader.conf* but this had no effect:

```
i915kms_load="YES"
kern.vt.color.1.rgb="#cc241d"
# definitions for all other colors follow but omitted in this example
```

Additionally, I changed */etc/ttys* to set `xterm-256color` in the third column instead of `xterm` but this does not enable 256 color support.

I want to stress that I want to change the number of colors when locally accessing the computer via its own keyboard and monitor in text mode (no gnome, Xorg, KDE...). Accessing the computer over SSH is something completely different.

Comment: That won't ever work, since FreeBSD console won't support it.  It's only a ***subset*** of xterm, in any case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing terminal emulators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23764/changing-terminal-emulators)

Comment: Then what are those options for? (`kern.vt.color.X.rgb`)? So there is no way to make the console support more than 8 colors?

Comment: I don't believe that to be a duplicate because they are talking about terminal capabilities over SSH while I want to increase the number of colors while directly accessing the machine via its own keyboard and monitor.

Answer (score 4):

FreeBSD console imitates xterm using *teken* (see [earlier discussion here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235635/alternate-screen-on-freebsds-sc-and-vt), and [mailing list](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-arch/2014-February/015081.html)).  It is not a complete implementation; the FreeBSD developers have trimmed out a few items from the terminal description (making the real *xterm* less useful on that platform).

FreeBSD console (teken) doesn't actually ***implement*** 256 colors.  See the [source-code](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/teken/teken.c?revision=333683&view=markup#l499):

```
499    /**
500      * The xterm-256 color map has steps of 0x28 (in the range 0-0xff), except
501      * for the first step which is 0x5f.  Scale to the range 0-6 by dividing
502      * by 0x28 and rounding down.  The range of 0-5 cannot represent the
503      * larger first step.
504      *
505      * This table is generated by the follow rules:
506      * - if all components are equal, the result is black for (0, 0, 0) and
507      *   (2, 2, 2), else white; otherwise:
508      * - subtract the smallest component from all components
509      * - if this gives only one nonzero component, then that is the color
510      * - else if one component is 2 or more larger than the other nonzero one,
511      *   then that component gives the color
512      * - else there are 2 nonzero components.  The color is that of a small
513      *   equal mixture of these components (cyan, yellow or magenta).  E.g.,
514      *   (0, 5, 6) (Turquoise2) is a much purer cyan than (0, 2, 3)
515      *   (DeepSkyBlue4), but we map both to cyan since we can't represent
516      *   delicate shades of either blue or cyan and blue would be worse.
517      *   Here it is important that components of 1 never occur.  Blue would
518      *   be twice as large as green in (0, 1, 2).
519      */
```

Those ***steps*** map application's attempts to use **256** colors onto the console's **16** colors.

Since it's not capable of doing what's asked, setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color` will not be very effective.

The **rgb** code is supported in a [different part](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/dev/vt/colors/vt_termcolors.c?view=markup) of the kernel, which lets one set the values in the (16-)color palette:

```
41  static struct {
42          unsigned char r;        /* Red percentage value. */
43          unsigned char g;        /* Green percentage value. */
44          unsigned char b;        /* Blue percentage value. */
45  } color_def[NCOLORS] = {
46          {0,     0,      0},     /* black */
47          {50,    0,      0},     /* dark red */
48          {0,     50,     0},     /* dark green */
49          {77,    63,     0},     /* dark yellow */
50          {20,    40,     64},    /* dark blue */
51          {50,    0,      50},    /* dark magenta */
52          {0,     50,     50},    /* dark cyan */
53          {75,    75,     75},    /* light gray */
54  
55          {18,    20,     21},    /* dark gray */
56          {100,   0,      0},     /* light red */
57          {0,     100,    0},     /* light green */
58          {100,   100,    0},     /* light yellow */
59          {45,    62,     81},    /* light blue */
60          {100,   0,      100},   /* light magenta */
61          {0,     100,    100},   /* light cyan */
62          {100,   100,    100},   /* white */
63  };
```

In the mailing list, I mentioned these screenshots:
[image: teken - 88colors]
[image: teken - 256colors]

Answer (score 3):

As M. Dickey says, the FreeBSD kernel's built-in terminal emulator *simply does not have* either indexed or 24-bit direct colour support.  Really, one should not treat it as xterm at all, and this is yet another case of the `xterm` terminal type being the wrong thing to use.  It is quite significantly different from actual XTerm in this and other respects.

The [terminfo database record for it uses the name `teken`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-teken).  I have a `teken` termcap entry which I add to FreeBSD termcap.  With these the `TERM` environment variable value can be set to its proper value of `teken`, not `xterm` or `xterm-256color`.

I ship my termcap entry with [the nosh toolset](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231011700/http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/), in the nosh-bundles binary package.  It is set up by the external configuration import subsystem, which uses `cap_mkdb` to create a combined termcap database (which also includes additions for `interix` and `linux`) in `/etc/system-control/convert/termcap/termcap.db`, which can be symbolically linked from `/etc/termcap.db`.  Or one can use the raw constituents in `/etc/system-control/convert/termcap/` to make a termcap database by hand onesself.

It also has a `teken-256color` entry.  This isn't for the FreeBSD terminal emulator.  It is for my terminal emulator, that provides a superset of `teken` that includes indexed and 24-bit direct colour capabilities amongst other things.  It is designed to be faithful to `teken` for the most part, that extending even to employing the same undocumented admixture of DECFNK and Xenix Console function key sequences that the FreeBSD terminal emulator actually generates.

```
JdeBP % console-decode-ecma48                          
^[OP^[OQ^[OR^[OS^[OT^[[17~^[[18~^[[19~^[[20~^[[21~^[[23~^[[24~
DEC KEY_PAD_F1
DEC KEY_PAD_F2
DEC KEY_PAD_F3
DEC KEY_PAD_F4
DEC KEY_PAD_F5
DEC F6
DEC F7
DEC F8
DEC F9
DEC F10
DEC F11
DEC F12
LF
^[[Y^[[Z^[[a^[[b^[[o^[[p^[[q^[[r^[[^^[[_^[[`^[[{
SCO Level2+F1
SCO Level2+F2
SCO Level2+F3
SCO Level2+F4
SCO Control+F5
SCO Control+F6
SCO Control+F7
SCO Control+F8
SCO Control+Level2+F9
SCO Control+Level2+F10
SCO Control+Level2+F11
SCO Control+Level2+F12
LF
JdeBP %
```

One of its uses is as a user-space replacement for the FreeBSD kernel terminal emulator that does not require X11, rendering to the framebuffer and reading input from keyboard and mouse HIDs.  The same colour cube as in M. Dickey's answer looks somewhat different:

[image: user-space virtual terminal]
<sub>(source: [jdebp.eu](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/user_space_virtual_terminal_1.png))</sub>

Because it is user-space, rather than built in to the kernel, it can afford to include multiple-font Unicode support, CIN-file-driven CJKV input methods, and compatibility with other built-in kernel terminal emulators, including the Linux one (hence the similarly enhanced `linux` termcap entry).

If you want more than 16 colours without X11, my terminal emulator or one of the several other full-screen framebuffer terminal emulators is the route that you have to take.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  "[256-colour and 24-bit True Colour support](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231011701/http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/user-vt-screenshots.html#ColourSGR)". *A quick look at user-space virtual terminals*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  *[Japanese input methods in nosh user-space virtual terminals](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231011815/http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/japanese-input-methods.html)*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  "[`console-decode-ecma48`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231012246/http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-decode-ecma48.xml)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177209/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303767/5132

Comment: This is a lot of information and I'm afraid I don't understand it all. It will take me a few days of rereading your answer and "further reading" articles hoping I will eventually understand it. Since `teken` is the built-in terminal emulater, I thought I could "replace" it by simply starting `tmux` from the shell but then I can't get 256 colors either. On the other hand, logging in via PuTTY over SSH does give me 256 colors. Did I just misconfigure `tmux`? Or is there something else still at play here?