# How can I list LS_COLORS in colour?

Tags: ls, colors

I recall that `eval "dircolors -b"` used to display the colours that `LS_COLORS` was using, based on the file types or extensions. It was not simply the colour values that were displayed *but the colours themselves.* I could see the colour in which a `.png`  or `.ogg` file would be displayed and change it if needed through a custom file.

I find that the output of `eval "dircolors -b"` is no more in colour.

Can someone kindly explain how I might get it back? Perhaps some environment variable is not getting set. Otherwise, is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm not really understanding how `eval "dircolors -b"` would ever display the output in color.  `eval` doesn't do any handling on the output of the commands.

Comment: This is what I *recall*; I might be wrong. If not that command, then some other similar command allowed me to see the extensions listed in the colours they would display in. That much I remember seeing. The question is what command shows output similar to `dircolors` but in the respective colours? Sorry for the bother.

Comment: Might be of interest: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/testing-ls-colors-in-zsh

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Your expansion of abbreviations at that weblink is very helpful. I have three abbreviations, `rs`, `ca`, and `mh` that are not included above. Can you please tell me where to find their expansions? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this script:

```
( # Run in a subshell so it won't crash current color settings
    dircolors -b >/dev/null
    IFS=:
    for ls_color in ${LS_COLORS[@]}; do # For all colors
        color=${ls_color##*=}
        ext=${ls_color%%=*}
        echo -en "\E[${color}m${ext}\E[0m " # echo color and extension
    done
    echo
)
```

Output:

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. I remember only the file extensions showing up in their respective colours. I need to do some digging up to understand what `IFS` is though.

Answer (score 0):

This version has some additional information and doesn't color the entire lines:

```
eval $(echo "no:global default;fi:normal file;di:directory;ln:symbolic link;pi:named pipe;so:socket;do:door;bd:block device;cd:character device;or:orphan symlink;mi:missing file;su:set uid;sg:set gid;tw:sticky other writable;ow:other writable;st:sticky;ex:executable;"|sed -e 's/:/="/g; s/\;/"\n/g')           
{      
   IFS=:     
   for i in $LS_COLORS     
    do        
        echo -e "\e[${i#*=}m$( x=${i%=*}; [ "${!x}" ] && echo "${!x}" || echo "$x" )\e[m" 
    done       
}
```

Part of [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17300/283843) by @karthick87 on Askubuntu
Also, see this answer: [What causes this green background in ls output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output/94505#94505)