# What causes this green background in ls output?

Tags: terminal, ls, colors

[image: screencap of ls output on linux machine]

There are two directories shown by 'ls'.  Normally directories anywhere are blue on black background.  But the first one is blue on green and impossible to read.  Why is this?  How to make it blue on black, or at least something light on something dark?

This is on Ubuntu 12.04, using bash in Gnome Terminal.  In Konsole, the blue is slightly darker, and possible to read, though could be way better.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Apart from coloring files based on their type (turquoise for audio files, bright red for Archives and compressed files, and purple for images and videos), `ls` also colors files and directories based on their attributes:

- Black text with green background indicates that a directory is writable by others apart from the owning user and group, and has the sticky bit set (`o+w, +t`).
- Blue text with green background indicates that a directory is writable by others apart from the owning user and group, and does *not* have the sticky bit set (`o+w, -t`).

[Stephano Palazzo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal) over at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) has made this very instructive picture over the different attribute colors:

[image: What the different colors mean in the terminal]

As [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94508/43779) pointed out, the color settings can be modified via [`dircolors`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dircolors). A list of the different coloring settings can be accessed with `dircolors --print-database`.

Each line of output, such as `BLK 40;33;01`, is of the form:

```
[TARGET] [TEXT_STYLE];[FOREGROUND_COLOR];[BACKGROUND_COLOR]
```

- `TARGET` indicates the target for the coloring rule
- `TEXT_STYLE` indicates the text style:

  - `00` = none
  - `01` = bold
  - `04` = underscore
  - `05` = blink
  - `07` = reverse,
  - `08` = concealed
- `FOREGROUND_COLOR` indicates the foreground color:

  - `30` = black
  - `31` = red
  - `32` = green
  - `33` = yellow
  - `34` = blue,
  - `35` = magenta
  - `36` = cyan
  - `37` = white
- `BACKGROUND_COLOR` indicates the background colors:

  - `40` = black
  - `41` = red
  - `42` = green
  - `43` = yellow
  - `44` = blue,
  - `45` = magenta
  - `46` = cyan
  - `47` = white

Fields may be omitted starting from the right, so for instance `.tar 01;31` means bold and red.

XTerm and most other modern terminal emulators support 256 colors.

A XTerm 256-color foreground color code is of the form:

```
38;5;[FOREGROUND_COLOR]
```

A XTerm 256-color background color code is of the form:

```
48;5;[BACKGROUND_COLOR]
```

where both `FOREGROUND_COLOR` and `BACKGROUND_COLOR` is a number the range 0-255. A full list of color codes for the 16 and 256 color modes are shown in the below screenshot:

[image: 16 and 256 color mode color codes]

Comment: so what does green only foreground mean? like I have [here](https://pasteboard.co/J81izJF.png)?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander: Executable files (see bottom row in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnT32.png)).

Answer (score 86):

The colors of `ls` can represent the permissions; the defaults for some systems is to show directories where everyone has write permissions with a green background:

[image]

You can change the colors by editing your `$LS_COLORS` variable using `dircolors` (from `man ls`):

```
   Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by  default  and
   with  --color=never.  With --color=auto, ls emits color codes only when
   standard output is connected to a terminal.  The LS_COLORS  environment
   variable can change the settings.  Use the dircolors command to set it.
```

The syntax is admittedly kind of annoying here but you can change this color by creating a file with the colors you want and saving it as `~/.dircolors`:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

That command will print the defaults into `~/.dircolors`. You will then need to edit that file and change this line:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

For example, to make it black text on a red background (see [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) for a list of color codes):

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 30;41 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

You don't need to have all the defaults, you can also just create a file with a single line, redefining just the one you want to change. Anyway, once you have created the file, load it with:

```
eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)";
```

And here it is in action:

[image]

To have that happen automatically, add the `eval` command above to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: The default colors often seem to indicate the original author hates us and our eyes though...

Comment: Thanks. WHy do you sometimes write ~/.dirname, and sometimes ~/dircolors, and sometimes ~/.dircolors? are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: Thanks. Why `eval "$(dircolors ~/dircolors)";` instead of more direct way such as `dircolors ~/dircolors`?

Comment: @Tim because dircolors only prints the settings, you need to eval it in order for them to be read.

Comment: for them to be read by whom?

Comment: @Tim `dircolors ~/.dircolors` will just read the `.dircolors` file and format it as a variable. The output is simply something like `LS_COLORS='foo=bar:baz=gaz'`. A variable and the value it is set to. In order for that to take effect, you need to actually set `LS_COLORS` to that value and that is what `eval` does.

Answer (score 34):

### tldr; How to just fix it?

To quickly fix the problem:

```
LS_COLORS+=':ow=01;33'
```

- Makes other-writable files show up as yellow on nobg
- Edit your shell profile (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, etc) to make this permanent.

---

### More details:

Replace `33` by `34` for `blue` on `nobg`. Even simpler, to make it `nofg` on `nobg`:

```
LS_COLORS+=:ow=
```

To make your change permanent, append it to your .profile:

```
echo "export LS_COLORS+=':ow=01;33'" >> ~/.profile
```

To view the non-extension related rules of `LS_COLORS`:

```
echo "$LS_COLORS" | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep -v '\*.'
```

`sed` puts each rule on one line and `grep` removes the rules beginning by `*.'.`

---

To explore the `ls` colors on your terminal, consider using

```
C="$LS_COLORS"
function sc () {
    echo "$LS_COLORS" | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep -v '\*.'
}
function t () {
    ls /mnt # Or the path to your example directory.
}
```

Then

```
LS_COLORS="$C:ow=38;5;250;48;5;025";t
```

As stated in another answer (that of Thomas Nyman), `38;5;` is the prefix for foreground x-term 256-colors, and `48;5;` for background x-term 256-colors. 256-colors isn't supported by all terminals though.

Also see [-What do the different colors mean in ls?-](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: I found dropping `LS_COLORS+=':ow=01;33'` into my `~/.zshrc` helped disable color-background for directories in a git-repo. This is on a Windows 10 machine with a Pengwin-WSL distribution. Now all directories within git-repo are readable.

Answer (score 21):

While all the technical answers are true, I would consider it a bit of an informal warning, that you dished out rights a bit to generously or copying criss+cross... (most often we all do, to get things initially working, eh?)

> How to make it blue on black,... ?

A good „de-greener“ to get back to rights you most likely want, is this statement:

```
chmod -R a-x,o-w,+X thatGreenFolderWithSubfolders/
```

Best understood what it does, if you understand the purpose of uppercase +X „special execute“, i.e. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

> It is only really useful when used with '+'
>   and usually in combination with the -R option for giving group or
>   other access to a big directory tree without setting execute
>   permission on normal files (such as text files), which would normally
>   happen if you just used "chmod -R a+rx...

Comment: Does not work on a NTFS filesystem e.g. used for MS Windows.

Comment: I was having problems with this in WSL2 mounts, this was the fix, thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Here are the 3 steps I used to change the colors:

First, copy the default colors to a file

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

Then modify this file. You can find some values for colors inside, and here are some more:

```
Code    Color
0   Default Colour
1   Bold
4   Underlined
5   Flashing Text
7   Reverse Field
31  Red
32  Green
33  Orange
34  Blue
35  Purple
36  Cyan
37  Grey
40  Black Background
41  Red Background
42  Green Background
43  Orange Background
44  Blue Background
45  Purple Background
46  Cyan Background
47  Grey Background
90  Dark Grey
91  Light Red
92  Light Green
93  Yellow
94  Light Blue
95  Light Purple
96  Turquoise
100  Dark Grey Background
101  Light Red Background
102  Light Green Background
103  Yellow Background
104  Light Blue Background
105  Light Purple Background
106  Turquoise Background
```

([source](http://twistedcode.org/2008/04/ls_colors-explained/))

And finally, add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file for the colors to be automatically loaded when you open a terminal:

```
eval 'dircolors ~/.dircolors' > /dev/null
```

For `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [[ -f ~/.dircolors ]] ; then
    eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)     
elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
    eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
fi
```

Comment: works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

To fix this try the **ow** parameter to the LS_COLORS

For example:

```
~LS_COLORS='fi=0:ln=5:pi=0:so=7:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=93:*.py=36:di=40:*.zip=33:*.tgz=33'
~ls -l
```

[image]

Now you add the **ow** (`OTHER_WRITABLE`) option

```
~export LS_COLORS='fi=0:ln=5:pi=0:so=7:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=93:*.py=36:di=40:*.zip=33:*.tgz=33:ow=0'
~ls -l
```

[image]
Bamm !!

Comment: If you wish to change the color via .dir_colors, you can add `OTHER_WRITABLE 34;43`. Thanks to: https://gist.github.com/jmoz/280005/3dca508fb193b6ae5d1f4a3f21efc7d90ecb0bde

Answer (score 1):

Well this mean that this folder has permissions if you run this:

> chmod og-w AU_LI

it will remove bgcolor :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tone of green in Putty to make the text readable.

Open Putty and go to Window\Colours,
select "ANSI Green",
set it to a darker green(R:0 G:70 B:0).

Answer (score 0):

Make all directories the same normal color. Copy/paste this to the end of the file `~/.bashrc`

```
export LS_COLORS+=':tw=01;34:ow=01;34:st=01;34'
```

Start a new terminal to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

In git-bash / MINGW the folder colors is often an issue for me. I like to use the following command as it makes things obvious:

```
eval "$(dircolors <(dircolors -p | grep -v '^[.#]' | sed -E '/DIR/s/[0-9;]{5}/01;33/g'))"
```