# Executable directory? And chmod o+w changing the terminal directory color?

Tags: directory, ls, chmod

1. What is an executable directory?
2. If `o+w` is set the directory changes colors to a background green, what does this mean? Why doesn't it do it for `ug+w`, but only for `o+w`?
3. Additional question after reading the comments: Is making a directory executable a security risk? If so, why?

Comment: why do you want to make a directory executable? that seems to pose a HUGE security risk

Comment: I'm playing around with permissions, trying to figure out the implications.

Comment: well if you are not the owner of the file and try to make the file you dont own executable I don't think it will like that as well as not in the group that owns the file, they will not want you to be able to make a file you don't own executable.

Comment: also are you running as sudo, root, regular user?

Comment: @jgr208 Where are you getting all this 'security risk' stuff from? Op doesn't mention anything about what this directory is being used for.

Comment: @dani-h Your recent edit radically changes the question. It doesn't even match the title any more.

Comment: Yeah I figured out a couple of things on my own, will edit.

Comment: @Patrick make a directory anywhere executable is a security risk. I work with DISA STIGS and there is a reason they don't let you make any directory globally executable it is also bad practice...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)

Comment: @jgr208 You are aware that directories have to have the executable bit set to be of any use correct? Are you also aware that `/`, `/bin`, and **numerous** other directories are globally executable? Are you also aware that when the op originally asked, he was also only setting the 'user' and 'group' bits, and not other?

Comment: @Leiaz It's an entirely different question after my edit. The title was misleading.

Comment: @Patrick yes I am. But imagine make a directory executable to a whole group that only the root should have able to get into? If you allow any user to get into that folder that doesn't pose a security risk?

Comment: @Patrick so if a malicious person was in the same group and saw the directory was executable that is not a risk?

Comment: @jgr208 Again, op doesn't mention *ANYTHING* about what the directory is being used for. Nowhere does he say only root should have access. Claiming that setting it as executable is "a HUGE security risk" is exceptionally premature.

Comment: It would not be a security finding that needs to be mitigated in certain environments? Imagine if you did that on a companies server. Maybe I like to teach good practice? @Patrick

Comment: @jgr208 - let's keep the commenting to the actual Q's details and not mythical content. If you have another issue to debate then take it to the chatroom or meta please.

Comment: It still answers your first question, the second one is [answered here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Colors

The coloring is controlled by the `DIR_COLORS*` files that reside under `/etc. For example on Fedora 19 I have the following 3 files:

```
$ ls -l /etc/DIR_COLORS*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5004 Jan 20  2014 /etc/DIR_COLORS
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5682 Jan 20  2014 /etc/DIR_COLORS.256color
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4646 Jan 20  2014 /etc/DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor
```

The coloring is completely cosmetic and keys off of the output that `ls` is generating. You can disable it like so:

```
$ ls --color=never <other options>
```

The `DIR_COLORS*` files can be viewed, they're just text, and have decent commenting, explaining their functionality. This line is why it's displaying as green:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

#### Executable directories

Directories need to be executable so that user's can `cd` into them and run commands. Without that bit, the directories cannot be accessed.

```
$ mkdir adir
$ chmod 644 adir
$ cd adir
bash: cd: adir: Permission denied
```

The reasons behind this are already extensively discussed in this other U&L Q&A titled: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened).