# Changing colors used by `ls` does not work in Emacs "Shell" mode

Tags: ls, emacs, colors

I followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94508/674 to change the colors used by `ls`. This works in bash.

When I open a buffer of "Shell" mode in Emacs (M-x shell), the change doesn't work. I wonder how I can apply the same change to Emacs "Shell" mode?

Answer (score 5):

Some versions of `ls` need to know from the terminfo database what color codes are supported by the terminal.

First, create the following file (dumb-emacs-ansi.ti):

```
dumb-emacs-ansi|Emacs dumb terminal with ANSI color codes,
    am,
    colors#8, it#8, ncv#13, pairs#64,
    bold=\E[1m, cud1=^J, ht=^I, ind=^J, op=\E[39;49m,
    ritm=\E[23m, rmul=\E[24m, setab=\E[4%p1%dm,
    setaf=\E[3%p1%dm, sgr0=\E[m, sitm=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m,
```

This is a Terminfo entry I created with support for Emacs' own brand of ANSI codes (supports only 8 colors, has bold, italic and underline as independent attributes). Compile it with `tic dumb-emacs-ansi.ti`.

Then add to your .bashrc:

```
if [ "$TERM" = dumb ] && [ "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    export TERM=dumb-emacs-ansi COLORTERM=1
fi
```

You can just run the export line in your existing shell session to update it without restarting bash.

Comment: Thanks. What are `tic` and `.ti` files?

Comment: @Tim the .ti file is the source code for the terminfo database entry, tic compiles and installs it in `~/.terminfo`. They're much more extensive for full-featured terminals, run `infocmp xterm` for an example.

Comment: What are they much more extensive for full-featured terminals than?

Comment: @Tim Well, on most terminals the application running in it can move the cursor, draw text anywhere, interpret the arrow keys, etc, and terminfo tells it how to do that. In Emacs shell mode, all it can do is type text, everything else is controlled by Emacs.

Comment: I also had to to this in order for ls to emit colors IFF the standard output is tied to a terminal: `alias ls="ls --color=auto"`. I found that `git log` would emit colors in the terminal, but not `ls` until I aliased it.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs `shell` mode is a dumb terminal that just exchanges strings with the shell; it doesn't allow terminal escape sequences like those which set colors. If you want a full terminal within emacs, use `M-x term`. (After doing this, you can quit out of it with `C-c k`; `term` grabs all the normal keys, since it is a full terminal emulator.)

EDIT: The suggestion to use `term` stands, but it seems that `shell-mode` does indeed allow colors, and `ls` somehow refuses to recognize this fact.

Comment: Actually... color setting sequences are just about the _only_ ones it allows, but it does allow them. The trick is getting `ls` to recognize this fact.

Comment: I just attempted `ls --color=always` within `shell-mode`. Colors nonetheless failed to appear.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you on? It works for me. What does `printf '\e[31mtest\e[m\n'` do?

Comment: Version is 24.5.1. `test` is output in what appears to be the correct color (some variant on yellow). Maybe `ls` is not getting the option somehow?

Comment: Hmm, yes, and `ls --color=always | xxd` shows no escape sequences, while in a real terminal emulator it has them.

Comment: Can you check if my answer makes it work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30591/discussion-between-tom-hunt-and-random832).