# Only color files according to file types?

Tags: files, directory, ls

When using `ls` to list files in a directory, [the files are colored according to their access permissions.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94505/674)

Is it possible to color the files only according to their file types (e.g. a regular file, a directory, a special file such as a socket, a symlink, ...)?

Comment: Hang on, do you want to _list_ files according to their type or _color_ them? Your title asks one thing and the question another.

Comment: color. sorry ....

Comment: OK, so the dupe should cover it. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: The duplicate is Linux-specific (and reading the suggested duplicate, *it* is not useful).  An answer points out that the OP's question depends on the system and can differ from Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading the manual page for the ls command relevant to your specific operating system and its version.

Shell environment variables might need to be set correctly.  For example, on Apple OS X, TERM needs to be set to a color capable console as defined by termcap and the CLICOLOR or CLICOLOR_FORCE variable need be set in order to then appreciate the result of the -G option to the ls command.

In other words, on OS X:

```
   export CLICOLOR=TRUE ; ls -lAG /
```