# What does it mean when ls -al gives output in red?

Tags: centos, ls

Centos 7, elasticsearch 5.x.

I am tracing an issue where elasticsearch becomes non responsive to logstash. (both running locally)

I measure the open handles, as we have had problems on the logstash side with this.

Today, when I run the below:

```
ls -al /proc/`pgrep -f elasticsearch`/fd
```

I see something I have never seen before: Some output lines in red (see below).

What does the red mean?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94498/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)

```
Red: Archive file
Red with black background: Broken link
```

In your case, those are broken links.

Answer (score 3):

It's a broken symlink. But since those FDs are open on virtual objects it's impossible to resolve them within the context of the filesystem regardless.