# Why are some files in bold & others not?

Tags: ls

[image]

I getting a permission denied when trying to copy my cisco image to the switch and I thought the bold text may indicate something I was unaware of.

Comment: Bold files are those with executable bit set (the 'x' flag in the first column).

Comment: That's XY.You insist it must be bold has something to do your can't-copy problem, and ask about it, but it's not related to your real problem.

Comment: @神秘德里克 He asked why some files and directories are in bold... . He may not know whether or not it's related to his problem but the question he posted is still valid.

Comment: That would be the "color" output from `ls`, which has an effect even on a monochrome terminal.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate because the answers of the dupe explain that all formatting (including colors and bold) just represents different permissions and/or file types. Specifically, the bold usually means that the file is executable.

Answer (score 0):

If the executable bit is set for any of root, group or user:
--x--x--x
for a file or directory, it will be in bold on some systems.

Don't depened on it though, it may or may not happen depending in the terminal you're using.