# Red dirs alert in bin folder, jvm dirs

Tags: arch-linux, java, manjaro

I was just hanging around in my dirs and I found some dirs that are displaying a red alert, all of them are related with jvm. I supposed that it could be a problem with jdk or some wrong installation process I may have done. My questions are:
1. What are they and where do they come from?
2. How can I delete them or at least make the red alert disappear?

Here are they: 
[image]
[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Ps: I have a Dell Latitude E6230 with Linux 4.19.79-1-MANJARO.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94505/117549

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

1. They are dead symbolic links
2. You can remove the red either by deleting the link (the bit on the left of the arrow) with `rm`, fix the link by replacing the target file (the bit on the right of the arrow) or by changing the link to point to somehthing else.

### Long answer

In `ls`, when you see something like `b -> a`, that means that `b` is a 'symbolic link' to `a`.

If I create a file `a` in the terminal `echo "test" > a`, then create `b` as a symbolic link to `a` `ln -s a b`, the output of `ls` would look like this (using screenshots to illustrate colour):

[image: normal ls output]

And if you `cat b` you will see `test`.

Now if I remove `a`, the source of our link `rm a`, it looks like this (my environment is setup differently to yours hence I don't have a red background):

[image: ls dead sym link]

If you remember, `a` contained the text `test`, if I now look at the contents of `b` I get an error:

```
cat: b: No such file or directory
```

The symlink points to `a`, which doesn't exist and so when trying to open the file `b`, it appears like it just doesn't exist.

Finally to clean up you can just `rm b`.

Dead symlinks are not harmful or dangerous, you can leave them and nothing bad will come of it.

The root cause of how it happened, at a guess, you installed something at some point which created the link to a file from the thing you installed. Then you uninstalled it and the uninstall process didn't clean up the symlinks it made.