# How does the command created by dircolors work?

Tags: colors, terminal-emulator

`dircolors` on a dircolors configuration file creates bash commands that, when run, can set up environment variable `LS_COLORS`.

What uses the environment variable? A terminal emulator? If so, why isn't the bash commands created by `dircolors` dependent on the type of terminal emulator, while we have to specify the type of terminal emulatorin the dircolors configuration file after `TERM`?

How is the environment variable used to color the output of commands such as `ls`, and bash auto-completition of pathnames?

Answer (score 0):

The `LS_COLORS` environment variable is passed to every program executed after its definition as are all environment variables. See `man execve`. `/bin/ls` is one program that pays attention to `LS_COLORS`, and uses it to produce pretty output.

```
strings /bin/ls | grep LS_COLORS
```

Other programs *could* use `LS_COLORS`, but the `/bin/ls` development team has control of changes and additions to `LS_COLORS`, so why? What would you use `LS_COLORS` for?

See `man dircolors dir_colors`.

Comment: Thanks. Is a terminal emulator involved? How is it involved? Why do I need to specify it in the dircolors configuration file?

Comment: This answer seems like it's written for someone who already knows the subject. Based on the assumption that someone asking about thing X doesn't know what it's for, it seems somewhat unproductive to turn around and ask questions about the same thing. As far as I understand, SE has comments that can be used to clarify unclear questions.